# How to make the "General" menu option selected by default in Magento admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, extensions, dashboard

When I install a new extension, that extension options are set to be selected by default on the side menu, and I would like to set the "General" menu option as selected regardless of any extension, just for convenience.

How to?

Comment: have a look at this - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13197/default-tab-selection-in-system-config

Comment: Yes, I found that answer 1 min ago and I could push the extension block down, but the extension options are still being loaded as default in admin instead of the "General" tab, 1st on the menu. See a screenshot here: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s633/sh/0e272e0c-59b4-4d47-8b18-ff5378a7e2f5/d1e80a93d6ccb7b3e358bbe300621d3b